# What operations are available for indexes in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I see that you can specify indexes in the fluent API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes. However, I do not see how the index can be used in Fluent API queries.

**Say I have defined a unique index:**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<PlayerRank>()
            .HasIndex(p => new { p.Date, p.World, p.Player })
            .HasName("UNIQUE_KEY")
            .IsUnique();
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

What can I actually do with this using the fluent API? What operations are available that take advantage of that?

Comment: The database engine will use the indexes as it sees fit, no action is required in your query

Comment: @ErikEJ So there are no operations available? Such as using an index in a `where` clause in the fluent api?